# Three Shift wise datetime checking in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have  problem to check  with sql queries in one of my projects. Actually, I have to get the records based on SHIFTNAME ie firstshift,secondshift and thirdshift with respect to date.

We have the following shift timings, the shifts will be in 24 hr formats

```
ShiftId   ShiftName       ShiftFrom    ShiftTo
-----------------------------------------------
   1      First Shift       07:00       12:00
   2      Second Shift      12:00       22:00
   3      Third Shift       22:00       07:00
```

My problem is I am getting the records correctly in shift1 and shift2, but not the records lies in shift3. I am going rounds, to solve this. I am using the following search query to fetch the records in all the shifts

```
select case when convert (varchar(5),GETDATE(),108) between (
  select ShiftFrom 
  from tbl_Shift_Master
  where ShiftId = 1
) and (
  select ShiftTo
  from tbl_Shift_Master
  where ShiftId = 2
) then 1 else 2 end as ShiftId
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you include the expected output

Comment: Please read the first two paragraphs in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without storing the shift times in variables, but it seems more clear to me:

```
DECLARE @ST1_S TIME
       ,@ST1_E TIME
       --
       ,@ST2_S TIME
       ,@ST2_E TIME
       --
       ,@ST3_S TIME
       ,@ST3_E TIME;

SELECT @ST1_S = CASE WHEN ShiftId = 1 THEN ShiftFrom  ELSE @ST1_S END
      ,@ST1_E = CASE WHEN ShiftId = 1 THEN ShiftTo  ELSE @ST1_E END
      --
      ,@ST2_S = CASE WHEN ShiftId = 2 THEN ShiftFrom  ELSE @ST2_S END
      ,@ST2_E = CASE WHEN ShiftId = 2 THEN ShiftTo  ELSE @ST2_E END
      --
      ,@ST3_S = CASE WHEN ShiftId = 3 THEN ShiftFrom  ELSE @ST3_S END
      ,@ST3_E = CASE WHEN ShiftId = 3 THEN ShiftTo  ELSE @ST3_E END
FROM tbl_Shift_Master;


SELECT CASE 
            WHEN convert (varchar(5),GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN @ST1_S AND @ST1_E THEN  1
            WHEN convert (varchar(5),GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN @ST2_S AND @ST2_E THEN  2
            WHEN convert (varchar(5),GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN @ST3_S AND @ST3_E THEN  3
        END
```

Comment: it's giving output as null

Comment: @YogeshHattekar Could you select the variables to ensure they have values?